# Is there a Linux image viewer that will show the desktop through transparent images?

Tags: ubuntu, software-rec, gnome, image-viewer

I'd like to load a transparent png and have all parts that are transparent show the desktop or underlying windows- is there a Linux image viewer that does this?  I'm using Ubuntu and Gnome.

I'm not asking the same as question as this:
[Linux: image viewer with transparent window?](https://superuser.com/questions/324447/linux-image-viewer-with-transparent-window)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I was able to do this in Ubuntu with the XFCE desktop using `pqiv`, which is in the Ubuntu repositories. Here's an example of me displaying a transparent PNG over both my desktop background and Firefox: [image: PNG transparency with pqiv]

The command I used to generate the transparent window was:

```
pqiv -c -c -i foo.png
```

This only worked when I turned "display compositing" on in XFCE. I bet if it works in XFCE there's a way to make it work in GNOME since they have so much in common.

Comment: That helped me find this which works in Ubuntu 10.10: "Open the GNOME Configuration Editor; press Alt-F2 to open the Run Application dialog and type gconf-editor. Click Run. Navigate to Apps->metacity->general. Check the compositing_manager box, and Metacity will immediately restart with compositing!"  http://tombuntu.com/index.php/2008/03/31/enable-metacity-compositing-in-gnome-222/   Your pqiv command works though sometimes there are issues with the screen not getting redrawn.  Thanks!

Comment: Might be more issues as well, the windows manager seems unstable now so I'll probably turn the compositing_manager setting off if I'm forced to restart it once more.  An 'always in foreground' mode would be nice also in combination with -c -c -c -c (which disables controls over the pqiv displayed window).

Comment: You might also try `qiv`, also in the repositories, which `pqiv` is based on--I found it worked less well on XFCE, but maybe it works better on GNOME. It does seem to have more features.

Answer (score 4):

```
sudo apt-get install qiv
qiv -p (yourimage)
```

Worked with default window manager under Mate Desktop on Ubuntu 14.04.  I used it with an `.svg` rather than a `.png`.

Comment: Works with transparent `.png` also. If you add a `devilspie` rule for `qiv`'s windows, you can get floating undecorated transparent windows.

Answer (score 2):

The transparency of the window itself is decided upon by the window manager. Which means that maybe it is possible to use [compiz](http://www.compiz.org/) to set any image viewer's window to be [transparent](http://www.ghacks.net/2009/08/22/get-some-serious-transparency-in-gnome-and-compiz/). This will only partially achieve what you are trying to do, since even the non-transparent parts of the image will be somewhat transparent while the transparent parts will be "more" transparent.

Comment: My gnome terminal windows (2.32.0) can have transparent backgrounds with solid colored text, so it ought to be possible.  Maybe I'll have a look at the source and see if I can implement it myself if nothing is out already there.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in https://superuser.com/a/870183/282396, you can use `transset` to make any window transparent. Unlike described in that answer I recommend just running `transset 0.5` and then clicking on the window you'd like to make transparent. This way you won't need to use any special image view.